# How should we decide whether to use documentDirectory or applicationSupportDirectory?

Tags: ios

We plan to store the following user files

- SQLite file
- Image files
- Audio files

We also provide an option for users, to upload and download the above files, to a 3rd party cloud storage.

I was wondering, should we use

```
FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
```

or

```
FileManager.default.urls(for: .applicationSupportDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
```

for the above file storage purpose?

Answer (score 23):

Historically we used the “Documents” folder, but nowadays the “Application Support” directory is the best place for files like this.

The [File System Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH2-SW13) says

> - Put user data in `Documents/`. User data generally includes any files you might want to expose to the user—anything you might want the user to create, import, delete or edit. For a drawing app, user data includes any graphic files the user might create. For a text editor, it includes the text files. Video and audio apps may even include files that the user has downloaded to watch or listen to later.
> - Put app-created support files in the `Library/Application support/` directory. In general, this directory includes files that the app uses to run but that should remain hidden from the user. This directory can also include data files, configuration files, templates and modified versions of resources loaded from the app bundle.
> - Remember that files in `Documents/` and `Application Support/` are backed up by default. You can exclude files from the backup by calling `-[NSURL setResourceValue:forKey:error:]` using the `NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey` key. Any file that can be re-created or downloaded must be excluded from the backup. This is particularly important for large media files. If your application downloads video or audio files, make sure they are not included in the backup.
> - Put temporary data in the `tmp/` directory. Temporary data comprises any data that you do not need to persist for an extended period of time. Remember to delete those files when you are done with them so that they do not continue to consume space on the user’s device. The system will periodically purge these files when your app is not running; therefore, you cannot rely on these files persisting after your app terminates.
> - Put data cache files in the `Library/Caches/` directory. Cache data can be used for any data that needs to persist longer than temporary data, but not as long as a support file. Generally speaking, the application does not require cache data to operate properly, but it can use cache data to improve performance. Examples of cache data include (but are not limited to) database cache files and transient, downloadable content. Note that the system may delete the `Caches/` directory to free up disk space, so your app must be able to re-create or download these files as needed.

Also see the [iOS Storage Best Practices](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/fall2017/204/) video.

---

If using the `.applicationSupportDirectory`, I’d suggest you use [`url(for:in:appropriateFor:create:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/filemanager/1407693-url) with `create` set to `true`:

```
let folderURL = try! FileManager.default
    .url(for: .applicationSupportDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
```

Comment: It's also helpful to note that other frameworks in an app may also use the application support folder so it is probably a good idea to create a folder within application support. It keeps things more organized and it's easier to clean up as needed. And, unlike the Documents folder, the `Library/Application Support` folder may not exist by default. So an app needs to create it if needed.

Comment: Thanks. As, I don't wish the app generated SQLite file, image files and audio files being able to access by a 3rd party app like File Manager. Then, I guess “Application Support” will be the best place for me?

Comment: Definitely not Documents folder. Likely the Application Support folder. The only question is whether any of these are files that can be downloaded again in the future. If so, you might consider the caches folder. But if these are user generated and/or cannot be downloaded again in the future, then the Application Support folder is perfect.

Answer (score 5):

It doesn't make much difference which you choose. The chief difference is in case you want to use a file browser or the Files app; they can look in your documents directory but not in your application support directory.

Also if you pick one and release the app and later change your mind, it's easy to migrate and change where the app stores its information.